# Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

We have assembly which has a reference to Oracle.DataAccess and connects to Oracle. Can i use this assembly, where only .NET Framework is only installed, without having Oracle.Client or Oracle Data provider.

Comment: Are you sure `Oracle.DataAccess` doesn't internally references Oracle.Client or Oracle.DataProvider ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with Oracle.DataAccess.?

Comment: Woudl like, to use Oracle.DataAccess requires Oracle Client or Oracle Dataprovider to be installed for conneting to Oracle server.

Comment: Assembly is just a wrapper on ODP.net to connect to Oracle database.

Comment: You need to install both.. because. Oracle client that handles client machine configuration , while..Oracle Data provider which part of programming .You need to install from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: You will get info. on above link;....

Comment: So we cant connnect to Oracle Database , programmaticaly using Oracle.DataAccess without installing  either Oracle Client or ODP.net right.